# SQL Server Wait Type

Tags: sql-server

I have been looking in Microsoft Documentation for `PWAIT_EXTENSIBILITY_CLEANUP_TASK` wait type and could not find anything there.

In my environment SQL 2019 on Linux I am having this significant amount of wait time spent on this wait type.

Could anyone give an insight on this?

Comment: I think https://dba.stackexchaange.com is a better place for this question since it's about database administration rather than programming.

Comment: For sure @DanGuzman

Comment: My team mate posted this on DBA exchange and got the following response

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/266789/208619